# How to set 1s delay while executing for loop in Javascript for first time before starting an execution

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to add 1second delay to JS For loop before starts execution. Only add delay before execution, not for every iteration.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < meters.length; i++) {
         meters[i].style.transition = meters[i].style.WebkitTransition = "stroke-dashoffset " + this.timeToWait+ "s linear";

        // additional styles for loader animation
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `setTimeout` function. Write your loop inside the callback for `setTimeout`.

See the code below.

```
    setTimeout(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < meters.length; i++) {
        meters[i].style.transition = meters[i].style.WebkitTransition = "stroke-dashoffset " + this.timeToWait + "s linear";

        // additional styles for loader animation

      }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: for loop calls only one time

Comment: Yes, the for loop will be called only once after the interval (here 1 second). If you want to re-run the for loop after every interval, use the ```setInterval``` function instead of ```setTimeout```. The syntax for both the functions is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The basic "sleep" in JS is implemented through [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
function myFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < meters.length; i++) {
        // code
    }
}
setTimeout(myFunction(), 1000);
```

In latest jQuery there is also [delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/).